# Realloc on NULL-valued (or undefined) pointer

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, realloc

I was reading about [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) and got confused about a point mentioned there. Consider the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    int* ptr = NULL;
    ptr = realloc(ptr, 10*sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any danger in allocating memory with `realloc` using the initially `NULL`-valued `ptr`? If instead of:

```
int* ptr = NULL;
```

I had this:

```
int* ptr; // no value given to ptr
```

would it be a problem to call `realloc` using `ptr`?

Comment: `ptr = realloc(ptr, 10*sizeof(int));` if realloc fails, you're leaking memory.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili but there's no memory to leak in this case.

Comment: @Kaihaku I was probably talking about the general case.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> Is there any danger in allocating memory with realloc using the
>   initially NULL-valued ptr

None

> 7.22.3.5
>
> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc
>   function for the speciﬁed size.

For the second part:

> ```
> int* ptr; // no value given to ptr
> ```
>
> would it be a problem to call realloc using ptr?

If you're using uninitialized pointers then that is a very serious problem indeed since you can't predict what their value will be. The function `realloc` only works correctly for `NULL` or values obtained from `malloc` / `realloc`.

> Otherwise, if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by a
>   memory management  function [...] the behavior is undeﬁned

Comment: Note that the reason for this is that most implementations of `malloc` store the length of the block right before the pointer returned (allowing `free` to know how much memory to free). If you give `realloc` an uninitialized pointer, it would think it was a valid pointer (a pointer is a pointer, all `realloc` can do is trust you). This implementation would then try to interpret the few bytes (size_t) before it as the size of the block, which would obviously be incorrect. That is why you must explicitly null the pointer so it is known that it isn't a valid address.

Comment: @Mk12: did you mean it stores the length of the block right after the pointer returned (or in better words, it stores the length of the block to which pointer points)? Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: @curvature: Suppose we have a very old computer, and its memory space consists of only 256 bytes. Pointers and `size_t` only needs to be 1 byte wide, because 1 byte can hold 256 distinct values. If you call `malloc(13)`, it will find some memory. It will return you a pointer to memory address, say, 0x5, but it actually stores the number 13 right before it, in 0x4. That way when you call `free` on 0x5, it looks at the byte before it (0x4), sees that it contains the number 13, and then it knows it has to free 13 bytes (so it won't just free 0x5, it will also free 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, etc.)

Comment: So if you `realloc` an uninitialized pointer (which could point to anything), it will look at the byte right before it, and maybe it contains the value 103, who knows? After allocating the new memory, it will free 103 bytes there because it assumes that's what you used to have allocated that you now want to `realloc`.

Answer (score 11):

With the specific code shown, there is no problem with using the null pointer initially.

If the variable `ptr` is uninitialized — not set to 0 or NULL — then any call to `realloc()` using it is dangerous; the behaviour is undefined and if you are lucky, the program will crash, but if you're unlucky, it will appear to work for a while, until something goes wrong later in the program where it will be hard to spot that the trouble is in code executed a long time ago.

There are those who argue it is better to use `malloc()` for the initial allocation and `realloc()` thereafter.  There is some justice to the suggestion, not least because you probably wouldn't use `ptr = realloc(ptr, 0);` to free the memory, even though you could do so (so you don't really need `malloc()` or `free()` because `realloc()` can do all three operations).  But the C90 standard requires `realloc(0, new_size)` to work equivalently to `malloc(new_size)`, and I know of no C library that behaves differently (but there might be some; I've only used a few C libraries, albeit mostly the most widely used ones).

---

However, in a more general case such as the following code, then there is a subtle problem with the code (but it is not to do with the initial null pointer):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    *ptr = NULL;
    size_t   len = 0;
    char     buffer[256];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))
    {
        size_t buflen = strlen(buffer) + 1;
        if (buflen > len)
        {
            if ((ptr = realloc(ptr, buflen)) == 0)  // Danger!
                // ... handle memory allocation failure ...
            len = buflen;
        }
        strcpy(ptr, buffer);
        // ... do something with ptr
    }
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the danger?  The danger is that if the second or a subsequent memory allocation fails and `ptr` is the only pointer to the allocated memory, you just overwrote its previous value with null.  That means you cannot free the allocated memory using `ptr` any more — you've leaked memory.  (For the first allocation, the initial value was 0, the overwritten value was zero, and nothing has changed; there is no memory leak.  That's why the loop was added to the code.)

#### Rule of Thumb

- Do not write `ptr = realloc(ptr, newsize);`

Save the new value into a separate variable until you've tested it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    *ptr = NULL;
    size_t   len = 0;
    char     buffer[256];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin))
    {
        size_t buflen = strlen(buffer) + 1;
        if (buflen > len)
        {
            char *new_ptr = realloc(ptr, buflen);
            if (new_ptr == 0)
                // ... handle memory allocation failure ...
            ptr = new_ptr;
            len = buflen;
        }
        strcpy(ptr, buffer);
        // ... do something with ptr
    }
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not leak memory on an allocation failure.

Auxilliary recommendation: do not use a variable called `new`; it will make it difficult to compile with a C++ compiler.  Even if you have no intention now of converting to C++ (and even though you would probably end up rewriting the memory management if you do), there's no virtue in using the C++ keyword `new` as a C variable name...unless you explicitly want to prevent compilation with a C++ compiler.

Comment: This was a really beautiful answer. Unfortunately I already accepted another (also good) one...

Comment: Usiing `ptr = realloc(ptr,newsize` is often fine in cases where a program would have no sensible way to continue usefully if the allocation fails, though wrapping realloc in a function that will output a diagnostic and call `exit` in case of failure may be more practical than having to scatter code all over the place to check the return value and abort in case of failure.  It's too bad there's no function for the purpose of shrinking an allocation without invalidating any pointers to it, since code could simply assume that such a function would always succeed (even if the system can't...

Comment: ...actually shrink the allocation for whatever reason, it could simply leave it as-is and user code wouldn't need to care).

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any danger in allocating memory using realloc using the initially NULL-valued ptr?

No, that would exactly be like a `malloc`.

> If instead of:
>
> ```
> int* ptr = NULL;
> ```
>
> I had this:
>
> ```
> int* ptr; // no value given to ptr
> ```
>
> would it be a problem to call realloc using ptr?

Yes, there would be a problem. If `realloc` doesn't get a `NULL`, it will try to expand memory starting from that location, or *may* try to `free` and `malloc` another part of memory. Since *uninitialized variables can have any value*, chances are very high, they are not a value `realloc` likes. If you are lucky, your program would immediately crash.