# C Socket Append Data To Buffer Gets Corrupted

Tags: c, sockets, memory-management

I'm still refining my C coding skills and keep running into issues with properly managing memory--go figure. Anyhow, I'm reading from a socket and I'm fine as long as my total response length from the socket it no bigger than my buffer size. I know this because when I increase the buffer size large enough for the incoming data, it works just fine for the larger payloads. Creating a really large "just-in-case" buffer on the stack isn't feasible, obviously, so I want to grow the buffer dynamically on the heap. Here's what I'm doing currently:

```
raw_response = NULL;

// Receive from the Web server
retcode = recv(server_s, in_buf, BUF_SIZE, 0);

while ((retcode > 0) || (retcode == -1))
{
  totalLength += retcode;

  if (raw_response == NULL) {
    raw_response = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*totalLength);
    memcpy(raw_response, in_buf, totalLength);
  } else {
    raw_response = (char*)realloc(raw_response, sizeof(char)*totalLength);
    memcpy(raw_response+previousLength, in_buf, retcode);
  }

  previousLength = retcode;
  retcode = recv(server_s, in_buf, BUF_SIZE, 0);
  if (retcode == 0 || retcode == -1) {
    printf("\n\nNo more data, bailing. Data length was: %lu\n\n", totalLength);
  }
}
```

If the raw_response is NULL, I know I have not received any data yet, so I use malloc. Otherwise, I use realloc so that I don't have to build up a new buffer. Instead I can just append the incoming data. So to get the end of the existing data after the first iteration, I take the address of raw_response and add the previous length to that and append the new data there assuming it's correctly appending on each subsequent call to recv().

The problem is that my final buffer is always corrupted unless I change BUF_SIZE to something larger than my total incoming data size.

Seem like it's probably just something simple I'm overlooking. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you have a lot of messages alloc memory in chunks (512 bytes, 1024) so you dont have to keep allocating resources. did you checked if the size have the \0 included?

Comment: [Please do not cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also, `previousLength = retcode` is wrong, you want `totalLength`. Also, if you get `-1`, that's an error, it doesn't mean you have to return a byte to the byte bank (which you are not doing correctly), it means you need to bail out now.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the aside. I've done that, but this is cross-platform C code and Visual Studio complains when I don't cast. I would guess there's some way to make it stop complaining, but I didn't look into it.

Comment: @n.m. Can you make your comment into an answer? The line with `previousLength = retcode;` was the problem. I'd like to give you credit. That's exactly what I was hoping for--something simple that I was overlooking. I really appreciate it.

Comment: "but I didn't look into it" — please do look into it ;)

Comment: @n.m. On a crusade are we? ;-) I'll see what I can find. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @n.m. From what I can tell, the Visual Studio compiler complains because it is actually a C++ compiler which requires a cast. Are you aware of any other reasons? There doesn't appear to be a setting to disable the warning.

Comment: Actually, it's not a warning. It's an error.

Comment: MSVC should compile files with ".c" extension in C mode, no C++ mode. You might just as well switch to C++. In C++ you *must* use this cast, so yeah. Whatever suits you. Note that C++ is a *very* different language from C. Good C programs are often bad C++ programs, even when they are valid C++ programs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is these lines:

```
memcpy(raw_response+previousLength, in_buf, retcode);
previousLength = retcode;
```

Your function will work for the first and second iterations but after that will start corrupting data. I assume you meant to write `previousLength += retcode;`

There are some other problems with the code which aren't the answer to your question. Firstly, what happens if realloc or malloc fails? You don't check for this in your little sample. Also, you can always just use realloc (which will act like malloc if the pointer is NULL see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134315/realloc-on-null-valued-or-undefined-pointer) SO question). i.e.

```
char *tmp = realloc(raw_response, sizeof(*tmp) * totalLength);
if (tmp == NULL)
     return -ENOMEM;
raw_response = tmp;
memcpy(raw_response + previousLength, in_buf, ret_code)
```

Secondly, you might call memcpy when ret_code is -1 (also changing totalLength by -1 which will again cause problems).

Comment: I appreciate the code review. Thanks for the additional suggestions. I will implement them. I am waiting to see if n.m. will convert his comment (in the question) to an answer so I can award it to him since he spotted the actual problem first and responded first. I'll give him a couple days to do so. If he doesn't do so soon, I'll award it to you. Thanks again for your input.