# What if NULL and size 0 are passed to realloc()?

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

Is the behavior implementation defined?  If NULL and size == 0 are passed to `realloc()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = NULL;

    ptr = realloc(ptr, 0);

    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("realloc fails.\n");
        goto Exit;
    }

    printf("Happy Scenario.\n");

Exit:
    printf("Inside goto.\n");

return 0;
}
```

The above code should print "realloc fails", right?  But it is not?  I've read somewhere that this call to `realloc` may return NULL also.  When does that happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realloc on NULL-valued (or undefined) pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134315/realloc-on-null-valued-or-undefined-pointer)

Comment: The possible duplicate doesn't address the specific point of the behaviour of `void *vp = realloc(NULL, 0);`.

Comment: I agree with @Jonathan here. it looks like the cited dup is missing a discussion of the behavior of realloc'ing for 0 elements, and information about the pointer you would get back. Older Microsoft platforms had a fair of trouble when allocating for 0 elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behavior is implementation defined.

From the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

Section 7.22.3.5 (`realloc`):

> *3* **If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the specified size.**  Otherwise, if `ptr`
>   does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management 
>   function,  or  if  the  space  has  been  deallocated  by  a  call  to
>   the `free` or `realloc` function,  the  behavior  is  undefined.  If 
>   memory  for  the  new object  cannot  be allocated, the old object is
>   not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

So `realloc(NULL, 0)` is the same as `malloc(0)`

If we then look at section 7.22.3.4 (`malloc`):

> *2*  The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` and whose value is indeterminate.
>
> *3* The `malloc` function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space.

The standard does not state what happens when `0` is passed in.

But if you look at the Linux [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc):

> The `malloc()` function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to
>   the allocated memory. The memory is not initialized. **If size is 0,
>   then `malloc()` returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can
>   later be successfully passed to `free()`**.

It explicitly states that the returned value can be freed but is not necessarily NULL.

In contrast, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d.aspx) says:

> If size is 0, malloc allocates a zero-length item in the heap and
>   returns a valid pointer to that item. Always check the return from
>   malloc, even if the amount of memory requested is small.

So for MSVC, you won't get a NULL pointer.

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful, specifically the contrast with MSDN.

Comment: "The standard does not state what happens when 0 is passed in." It does, just in the section intro instead of in the realloc paragraph. For C1x, it's under "7.22.3 Memory management functions": "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object".

Answer (score 12):

realloc(3) doc:

> If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size

malloc(3) doc:

> If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be success‐fully passed to free().

So yes, it is implementation defined, you'll either get null or a pointer you can free.

Comment: If you get a non-null pointer, the pointer you get should be freed to avoid leaks, but cannot be dereferenced (because it provides 0 bytes of legitimately accessible memory).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "... the pointer you get should be freed to avoid leaks" applies to all  pointers allocated with 0 or non-zero sizes that do not return `NULL`.  Eventually they should be free'd to avoid leaks.  OTOH, if a `malloc(0)` returns non-`NULL`, freeing it right away may reduce memory usage and maybe a good idea, but it is not a _leak_ issue.

Comment: I wonder what benefit there is, if any, to guaranteeing that a non-null pointer will be unique, rather than simply specifying that each value returned from a zero-sized `malloc()` , `calloc()`, or `realloc()` will be considered distinct *for purposes of passing to `free()` or `realloc()`*, but might happen to compare equal to pointers received from other zero-size operations.  It's advantageous not to perform an allocation for a zero-sized allocation request, but having size-zero requests return a pointer to a static dummy object which both `free` and `realloc` would ignore...

Comment: ...would make it possible for zero-sized requests to refrain from allocating anything without having to return a null pointer.

Answer (score 6):

The call

```
realloc(NULL, size);
```

is equivalent to

```
malloc(size);
```

And what `malloc()` does when asked to allocate 0 bytes is a bit unclear, the standard doesn't say. I think it's implementation-defined. It basically "doesn't matter"; either it returns `NULL`, or it returns a pointer where you can legally access zero bytes, those are pretty much alike. Both can be passed to `free()`.

Comment: No, don't pass `NULL` to `free()` - that is bad practice and could cause a crash depending on the implementation.

Comment: "If ptr is a null pointer, the function does nothing". Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/