# 448 bytes in 28 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1 - problems with FREED memory

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-management, valgrind

I have created an array of structs. Each element of the array is meant to allocate up to 4 digits; there can be less digits. Initially, the are set to 0. I have some memory leaks in program and I would like to ask about the first one:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ELEMENTS 8
#define NUM_INT 4   //Number of digits

typedef struct sth {
    int* numbers;
    int how_many;  //How many cells with 4 digits
} sth;


void create(sth** tab) {
    *tab = realloc(*tab, ELEMENTS * sizeof(**tab)); 
    for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
        sth cell; 
        cell.numbers = calloc(NUM_INT, sizeof (*cell.numbers));
        cell.how_many = 1;
        (*tab)[i] = cell; // Put in original array.
     }
     (*tab)[ELEMENTS-2].numbers[0] = -1; // Don't bother about the values
     (*tab)[ELEMENTS-1].numbers[0] = 1;
}

void clear(sth** arr) {
    free(*arr);
    *arr = NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    sth* arr = NULL; // Don't need to initialise to null here.
    create(&arr);
    //There have been functions, but I commented them out
    clear(&arr);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I get by Valgrind:

```
    ==58759== 448 bytes in 28 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1                                       
    ==58759==    at 0x4837B65: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:752)                                                             
    ==58759==    by 0x1091D6: create (address_of_a_file)                       
    ==58759==    by 0x10A3F4: main (address_of_a_file)                                 
    ==58759==
```

Earlier I have used realloc instead of calloc and vilgrind indicated line:

```
sth cell;
sth cell.numbers = NULL;
cell.numbers = realloc(cell.numbers, NUM_INTS*sizeof(*cell.numbers));  //this line
```

As I have written, in the whole program occur memory leaks, but I want to track the first source of them.

For me it seems as if I have created new allocated memory and have not freed the previous content. However I don't know, what is the cause of the problem here, because I free the memory at the end of the program.

I would appreciate your suggestions and explanations.

Comment: You're **not** freeing the memory at the end of the program. **each and every** call to calloc/malloc/realloc **must** be coupled with exactly one free. You're not freeing **that** memory that you allocate with `calloc`.

Comment: So I have to prepare the function for each arr[i]? free(arr[i])?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Antti Haapala not quite, calls to realloc with a size of 0 are actually frees, the size needs to be > 0 to be an allocation

Comment: @PaulFloyd that's not guaranteed by C standard. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/42303040/918959

Comment: @PaulFloyd Also: https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-alpha/2019-08/msg00105.html

Comment: On the contrary, C17 7.31.12 says that "Invoking realloc with a size argument equal to zero is an obsolescent feature."

Comment: Fair comment, and I wasn't aware of this change. GNU libc seems to have a build time macro to decide if realloc of size zero frees, and jemalloc has an option to `mallctl` called "opt.zero_realloc", but the default is strict i.e., `malloc(0)` behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The solution suggested by @AntiiHappala was:

```
void clear(sth** arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
          free((*arr)[i].numbers);
    }
    free(*arr);
}
```