# How can i automatically increase memory allocation for a struct in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

I am building a small program that takes name and age as input (stored in a struct) and spits out the output. One of the problems that I am facing is I have to enter the number of people I am going to store, something that I am sure I can solve with `realloc()` it's just not working. Here is what I got so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct info
{
    int age;
    char name[30];
};

int main()
{
    struct info *Ptr;
    int i, num;

    printf("Enter number of people");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    // Allocates the memory for num structures with pointer Ptr pointing to the base address.
    Ptr = (struct info*)malloc(num * sizeof(struct info));

    for(i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter name and age:\n");
        scanf("%s %d", &(Ptr+i)->name, &(Ptr+i)->age);
    }


    for(i = 0; i < num ; ++i)
        printf("Name = %s, Age = %d\n", (Ptr+i)->name, (Ptr+i)->age);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to realloc inside the first for loop, but it wasn't working even if it makes sense to have it there. Have also tried to convert the loop to a while loop like this:

```
     while(input != "stop)
    {
      allocate more memory
}
```

How can I use realloc to in order to skip having to enter the persons number before entering them?

Comment: I know, but i can't do that before i can do realoc in the right way before i can move on to comparing the input of the struct and the input variable

Comment: Could you explain clearly what you are you trying to achieve? you don't want to take no.of people, and then adjust if no.of people increase, is this is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: "*it wasn't working*" what actually did not work?

Comment: While realloc allows you to extend the allocation, it can be very inefficient.  If the records do not need to be located in contiguous memory, a linked list may be appropriate.  Adding records is fast and efficient, accessing records less-so.

Answer (score 2):

`realloc` is the correct way. Just start with `Ptr = NULL` and `num = 0` and on each input increase the number of elements by one.

Remember to limit the number of characters scanf can read, otherwise you may buffer overrun.

Also I find `Ptr[i]` way easier then `(Ptr+i)->`.

Also compare strings with `strcmp` not using `!=`. The `!=` will compare pointers to strings, not strings themselves.

As I like reading the whole line, then scanning the line, I would do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct info
{
    int age;
    char name[30];
};

int main()
{
    struct info *ptr = 0;
    size_t num = 0;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter name and age. If you want to stop, type only 'stop'.\n");

        char line[256];
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) { 
             fprintf(stderr, "fgets error");
             exit(-1);
        }

        if (!strcmp("stop\n", line)) {
             break;
        }

        struct info tmp;
        if (sscanf(line, "%29s %d\n", tmp.name, &tmp.age) != 2) {
             fprintf(stderr, "error parsing line\n");
             exit(-1);
        }

        ptr = realloc(ptr, (num + 1) * sizeof(*ptr));
        if (ptr == NULL) { 
             fprintf(stderr, "error allocating memory!\n");
             exit(-1);
        }

        ptr[num] = tmp;
        ++num;
    }


    for (size_t i = 0; i < num ; ++i) {
        printf("Name = %s, Age = %d\n", ptr[i].name, ptr[i].age);
    }

    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) < 0) {...}` fgets() returns a `char*` .This could be NULL, but never `< 0` Your compiler should have warned you.

Comment: @joop right, right, you are right. That standard library, each function has different error handling.

Comment: You can do pointer arithmetic if the pointers are pointing at the same array (or one is an array and the other points to one past the last element). but I don't think it's ever undefined to compare two pointers for equality.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i noticed you're not using malloc, how's that possible?

Comment: @HannaM: "*not using malloc, how's that possible?*" You might like to read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12134328/694576

Comment: @HannaM `realloc(NULL, ...)` is equal to `malloc(...)`. That's why it's important for `ptr = NULL` the first time realloc is called.

Comment: At least by convention this `exit(-1);` ought to be `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` (`EXIT_FAILURE` comes with `stdlib.h`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure of the no.of.elements you want to allocate and do it based on the users choice, then you can follow the below approach.

It starts with one element and the memory is reallocated as when the user wants to add new element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct info
{
  int age;
  char name[30];
};

int main()
{
    struct info *Ptr=NULL;
    int i=0, num;

    char c='Y';
    while(c=='Y'||c=='y') {

            Ptr=realloc(Ptr,(i+1)*sizeof(struct info));
            if(Ptr==NULL)
                 break;
            printf("Enter name and age:\n");
            scanf("%s %d",&Ptr[i].name,&Ptr[i].age);
            printf("Do you want to cont?\n");
            scanf(" %c",&c);
            i++;
    }
    num=i;

    for(i = 0; i < num ; ++i)
            printf("Name = %s, Age = %d\n", (Ptr+i)->name, (Ptr+i)->age);
    free(Ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a data struct like `vector`.

1. `vector_init` init vector.
2. `vector_push` push `val` to `vector`, if necessary,  will `realloc` memory.
3. `vector_output` output the `vector`.

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INIT_SIZE 1

struct info
{
    int age;
    char name[30];
};

struct vector {
    struct info* p;
    int n;
    int index;
};

void vector_init(struct vector* ve) {
    ve->n     = INIT_SIZE;
    ve->index = 0;
    ve->p     = malloc(sizeof(struct info) * ve->n);
}

void vector_push(struct vector* ve, struct info* tmp) {
    if (ve->n == ve->index) {
        ve->n *= 2;
        ve->p = realloc(ve->p, sizeof(struct info) * ve->n);
    }
    ve->p[ve->index++] = *tmp;
}

void vector_output(const struct vector* ve) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ve->index; ++i)
        printf("Name = %s, Age = %d\n", ve->p[i].name, ve->p[i].age);
}

int main()
{
    struct vector ve;
    vector_init(&ve);

    for (;;) {
        struct info tmp;
        printf("Enter name and age:\n");
        scanf("%29s", tmp.name);
        if (strcmp(tmp.name, "stop") == 0)
            break;
        scanf("%d", &tmp.age);
        vector_push(&ve, &tmp);
    }
    vector_output(&ve);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works and simplifies in long programs, I think adding comments and explaining would be better for op.

Comment: This "%s" should be "%29s" to avoid overflow.

Comment: Error checking is missing completely.

Answer (score 0):

To answer exactly, you can first read the input to temp variables and check if you need to stop: Break the loop if so. Or continue and reallocate the 'storage' array by increasing it's size by one and copying the values you just read to the 'storage' array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct          info
{
  int           age;
  char          name[30];
};

int             main()
{
  struct info * infos = 0;
  int           num = 0;
  char          input_name[30];
  int           input_age;

  while (1)
    {
      printf("Enter name and age:\n");
      int r = scanf("%29s", input_name);
      if (r == EOF || strcmp(input_name, "stop") == 0)
        break;
      scanf(" %d", &input_age);

      infos = realloc(infos, sizeof(struct info) * (num + 1));
      infos[num].age = input_age;
      memcpy(infos[num].name, input_name, sizeof(char) * 30);
      num++;
    }

  for(int i = 0; i < num ; ++i)
    printf("Name = %s, Age = %d\n", infos[i].name, infos[i].age);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `"%s"` should be `"%29s"` to avoid overflowing `input_name`.

Comment: Also error checking for the 2nd call to `scanf()` is missing as well as for `realloc()`.

Comment: And this test `(strcmp(input_name, "stop") == 0 || r == EOF)` has to be the other way round: `(r == EOF || strcmp(input_name, "stop"))` as you do not want to call `strcmp()` in case of `EOF`.