# Why do this use of realloc give sigtrap fault?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, segmentation-fault, realloc

```
int i=0;
float *array;
while(i<20)
{   
    array=realloc(array,((i+1)*sizeof(float)));
    i++;
}
```

Whats wrong with this code?

```
    array=realloc(array,((i+1)*sizeof(float)));
```

This line gives `sigtrap`.

Comment: You are calling `realloc` with an **uninitialized** argument (`array`) on the first loop. Set that to `NULL` in the declaration: `float *array = NULL;`.

Comment: This is also a worthwhile read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38213123/10871073

Comment: Is this just an experiment or part of production code? If it is the latter, this code should be replaced as the reallocation at each iteration has no use actually.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12134328/11336762) answer is relevant too, in case @Adrian wants to write its answer. (TLDR: realloc with or without a NULL pointer as a parameter)

Comment: Compiler warnings can catch this.  `-O -Wall` for gcc, `-O -Wconditional-uninitialized` for clang.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show it (this is the reason we recommend you to post a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) but the most probable reason for it to give you an exception is:

- your `array` pointer is automatic (this is, declared inside a function body or an inner block, not a global variable)
- you don't initialize it, so it has any value.
- If you pass `NULL` to `realloc()`, then realloc tries to allocate a *completely new block*, but if you pass something different than `NULL` it consider it represents an already allocated block (which it isn't) and the computer explodes.

Just change your declaration:

```
float *array;
```

to

```
float *array = NULL;
```

and rerun.

## Note

It is very important you post a complete example, because if you don't we have to guess what you could have done.  In your example, should the variable had been defined as a global variable (out of any functions) then it should have been initialized as `NULL`, and your bug had gone away.  In this case, trying to focus us in the `realloc()` function, you have just eliminated the bug, making us to *try and guess*.